# does a JSON parser exist that parses numbers into 32-bit floats instead of doubles?

Tags: json

I have an object that exists with numeric values that are 32-bit floats.  If I JSON-encode it and then JSON-decode it, what were originally floats would be promoted to doubles with most parsers.  Do any parsers exist that parse decimal-numbers as 32-bit floats instead of doubles?

[rfc7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) section 9 states that:

> > An implementation may set limits on the range and precision
> > of numbers.

However, I'm unaware if there are parsers that opt to do this.

Edit: Possible languages for the parser: C, Python, or R

Comment: In which language?

Comment: Thanks: C, Python, or R.  I will edit the question to be more specific.